# why shader compile error with attribute int (Android opengl es2)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

why shader compile error with attribute int? (Android opengl es2)

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;
attribute int a_fckLen; ///--error compile 
attribute float a_fckLen; //--compile ok

void main()
{

        gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position;
}
```

but float compile OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From GLSL ES 1.00 (the one GL ES 2 uses) specification:

> #### 4.3.3 Attribute
>
> ...
>
> The `attribute` qualifier can be used only with the data types `float`, `vec2`, `vec3`, `vec4`, `mat2`, `mat3`, and
> `mat4`. Attribute variables cannot be declared as arrays or structures.